# SASS &body? does not work but &.class does

Tags: sass

For the following SASS when class-a also has class-b then the color applied is blue.

However when the body element has class-a I would expect the color to be red, but instead this results in an error.

```
.class-a {
    &.class-b {
        color: blue;
    }
    &body {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you perhaps mean `&.class-b` which would result in `.class-b.class-b`?

Comment: Even if this worked in Sass, the selector would generate as `.class-abody` instead of the desired `body.class-a`.  You would need to have it written as `body&` instead of `&body`.

Comment: @Christoph yes sorry, have updated my question.

Comment: @cimmanon so is there a way of nesting a selector within .class-a that targets the body element when it also has the class of class-a?

Comment: Are you looking for a [parent selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)?  Or do you just want a `body.class-a` selector?

Comment: This isn't how nesting works. If you want `body.class-a`, you need to reverse the current nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible.

> Currently, & is syntactically the same as an element selector, so it can't appear alongside one. I think this helps clarify where it can be used; for example, foo&bar would never be a valid selector (or would perhaps be equivalent to foo& bar or foo &bar).

There is discussion to change this behavior, but it may be a long ways off before this becomes a part of Sass.

- https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/282
- https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/286

In the mean time, all you can really do is this:

```
.class-a {
    &.class-b {
        color: blue;
    }
}

body.class-a {
    color: red;
}
```